# Android SQL IF / CASE / Update if exists

Tags: android, sql, if-statement, sql-update, case

i've got a big problem with the android Api. 
I'm trying to inset some Values in a SQL-Database and if the key already exist i want to update.

normaly with SQL it's no problem but android throws alwas an error.

my code:

```
"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "+table+" WHERE Name='"+key+"')" +
" UPDATE "+table+" SET (Value='"+Value+"') WHERE Name='"+key+"'" +
" ELSE" +
" INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,Value) VALUES ('"+key+"','"+Value+"')";
```

the error i alwas get:

```
09-19 19:56:46.311: E/AndroidRuntime(32454): Caused by:      
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CASE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE Name='AppVersion')THEN UPDATE Settings SET (Value='0.5 beta') WHERE Name='AppVersion'ELSE INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,Value) VALUES ('AppVersion','0.5 beta')`
```

I've also tried to use "CASE" but it doesnt work neither.

```
"CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "+table+" WHERE Name='"+key+"')" +
"THEN UPDATE "+table+" SET (Value='"+Value+"') WHERE Name='"+key+"'" +
"ELSE INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,Value) VALUES ('"+key+"','"+Value+"')";
```

Please can anybody tell me how it works.

PS.: sorry for bad english.

Comment: Do you know that sqlite has REPLACE keyword ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite (obviously) does not support the syntax that you are trying to use.

There are basically two options:

- Use SQLite's "[ON CONFLICT REPLACE](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)" syntax with an INSERT statement

  - this requires a unique constraint (in this case, on the 'Name' column).
  - be aware that this will first delete the old row, and then insert a new one.
- If delete/insert is unacceptable to you, then you'll probably have to resort to attempting to update first, get the update count, and if it's zero, do the insert.